# Unable to download a CSV file using Flask Python

Tags: python, flask

I want to download a CSV file which is populated on runtime. The scenario is that user will submit a form and the CSV file will contain the submitted form information. The code is given below.

```
if request.method == "POST":

    todo = request.form.get("todo")
    if(todo is not None):
        captions = todo.split("&")
        for caption in captions:
            caption = caption.split("=")[0]
            caption = caption.replace("+", " ")
            print(caption)
    csv = 'foo,bar,baz\nhai,bai,crai\nfoo,bar,baz\nhai,bai,crai\n'  
    response = make_response(csv)
    cd = 'attachment; filename=mycsv.csv'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = cd 
    response.mimetype='text/csv'
    print(response)
    return response
```

The response is (200 OK) but i am unable to download the file locally which means that download doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('app.view_') }}" ..> Download Csv From Db </a>
```

py:

```
@app.route("/")
def view_():
conn = None
cursor = None

try:
    conn = db.connect("") # mysql or something

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql_query = """ select * .. """
    cursor.execute(sql_query)

    result = cursor.fetchall()  # fetchone()

    output = io.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(output)

    line = ["column0", "column1", "column2", "column3"]
    writer.writerow(line)

    for row in result:
        line = [row[0], row[1], str(row[2]), row[3]]
        writer.writerow(line)

    output.seek(0)

    return Response(output, mimetype="text/csv",
                    headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=track_report.csv"})
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Try this way instead of your own way

Comment: Well, i am not using any SQL queries i am just using plain form.

Answer (score 0):

Importance of csv file is we already have opened a file to write data.
If you read/write a file we use context manager helping us for handling `__enter__` and `__exit__` situations. Shortly when you open file for reading or writing, finally context manager is going to close it.

```py
from flask import Flask, send_file
from io import StringIO
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)

# With Flask 2.0 we have `post` decorator
@app.post('/csv/')  # `GET` is better to download file
def download_as_csv():
    """
        your logic code here
    """
    
    plain_str = 'foo,bar,baz\nhai,bai,crai\nfoo,bar,baz\nhai,bai,crai\n'
    byte_like_str = StringIO(plain_str)  # it is like a opened file
    with open('return.csv', newline=''):
        csv.reader(byte_like_str, delimiter=' ')
        # context manager is going to save `csv` file
        
    return send_file('return.csv', 
                    mimetype='text/csv',
                    download_name='my_file.csv'
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

is going to return the csv file like:

```
|foo|bar|baz |
|hai|bai|crai|
|foo|bar|baz |
|hai|bai|crai|
```

Comment: I want to download the CSV in the form post event. Can you check my code please?

Comment: `@app.post('/csv/')` handling your post request. You can only get your post data with `request.form.get('smt')` code. This is why extracting your event is more accurate for development. Divide and conquer is helping you on development.